# If I set more than one address object in the addresses array , then is it necessary to provide addresses to both fields?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, smartystreets

Here i am using smarty street plugin for address verification . I have Multiple address fields on the form . I want to map all the fields. but I want to keep some fields optional.

```
 var liveaddress = $.LiveAddress({
             key: htmlKey,         // An HTML key from your account
             debug: true,         // Show debug stuff
             waitForStreet: false, // Hides autocomplete suggestions until a street is entered
             AutoVerify:true,

             addresses:
             [{
                 ID: 'Complainant1',
                 street: '#complainantOneStreetAddress',
                 city: '#complainantOneCity',
                 state: '#complainantOneState',
                 zipcode: '#complainantOneZip'
             }
             ,

             {
                 ID: 'Complainant2',
                 street: '#complainantTwoStreetAddress',
                 city: '#complainantTwoCity',
                 state: '#complainantTwoState',
                 zipcode: '#complainantTwoZip'
             },

             {
                 ID: 'Suspect',
                 street: '#suspectStreetAddress',
                 city: '#suspectCity',
                 state: '#suspectState',
                 zipcode: '#suspectZip'
             },

             {
                 ID: 'Vehicle',
                 street: '#vehicleOwnerAdddress',
                 city: '#vehicleOwnerCity',
                 state: '#vehicleOwnerState',
                 zipcode: '#vehicleOwnerZip'
             },

             {

                 ID: 'BusinessInfo',
                 street: '#businessStreetAddress',
                 city: '#businessCity',
                 state: '#businessState',
                 zipcode: '#businessZip'


             }

             ]

         });
```

The problem is I want to keep ID: 'Complainant1' required but other should be optional. 
Right now It gives me error on submit.As other ID's in the array are empty. Is It possible? Can you suggest me a different approach instead?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are using either version 2.8.22 or version 2.8.23 of the plugin. 2.8.23 is preferred and is currently being published.
2. Make sure you are using the correct syntax for the plugin. `AutoVerify` should be `autoVerify` and `ID` should be `id`.
3. You will need to deactivate the plugin via `addressID` depending on if a particular address in the form is blank or not. From what I understand, you want to disable the plugin whenever an address is completely blank (besides the `Complainant 1`).

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/camiblanch/34L81jvh/) that shows how to do this. You will need to put in your own key-token pair for it to work properly in the example.